# Pre-set formatting on asp.net pages.

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, visual-studio-2010, formatting

I am newish to Asp.net. I have inherited a web application project. When I create a new page it already has some formatting on the top even though I don't use any master page when creating the page. This I can see when I build the page.  I am using ASP.Net 4.0, C# language.

For the life of me I cant figure out as in the underlying code for the file there is no reference to any css or any elements. The code for page.aspx is as follows:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The code behind is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help I can get.

Comment: That's an empty page.  What exactly is the issue here?

Comment: @David He says that he sees a formatting on his page even thought he isnt inheriting the page from masterpage.

Comment: @Khan: I read that part, but there's no information about what that means.  What is "formatting"?  There is no content to *be* formatted.  If he's seeing something unexpected in the rendered client-side code, maybe he'd like to share it?  Because the code shown has no "formatting."

Comment: What is the rendered HTML for that code? As is, you are just showing a blank page and there is no issue. Also, check the global.asax file to see if it is doing anything.

Comment: This is the formatting I see:       
http://imgur.com/0z5wnjM

Comment: The rendered code is as follows:

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head><title>

    </title><link href="App_Themes/Default/flexslider.css"     type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><link     href="App_Themes/Default/PublicStyle.css" type="text/css"     rel="stylesheet" /></head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>

Answer (score 4):

Oh Actually when you create a page in Visual studio. He create some by default code file and a project structure.  Just why you show different type of file on solutions.

See on your aspx page header its define cs code file as CodeFile="Test.aspx.cs" and also Inherits test.
 Also .csproj file that contains assembly references
 .projRefs.sln file that contains the current project and all referenced projects

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. There was a theme applied which was adding reference to a stylesheet when compiling the page. I added disable theming tag which removed this reference for the particular page.